# Unexpected results from imaginary exponentiation in Numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I am using numpy to prototype a FFT hw accelerator. And while I was debugging the base 2x2 case when I noticed something odd.

Per every calculator I could find e^(-i * pi) is equal to -1.

However when I have Numpy do `np.exp(-1j*np.pi)` it returns `(-1-1.2246467991473532e-16j)`

I can't read this number but it doesn't look like -1 and when you add -1 to it it doesn't start looking like 0.

Are the online calculators I am using here wrong? Or perhaps I am notating the math incorrectly?

Comment: `-1.2246467991473532e-16` is basically zero. This is the same as `-0.0000000000000001225` - is it not close enough to zero? So, `-1-1.2246467991473532e-16j` is _almost_ `-1`. Also see https://0.30000000000000004.com

Comment: What is the leading -1 trying to say? It is -1-1.....

Comment: It's the imaginary number: `-1` is the real part and `-1.2246467991473532e-16j` is the imaginary part.

Answer (score 2):

It's a floating point error -
`-1.2246467991473532e-16` is `-0.00000000000000012246467991473532` which for *most* intents and purposes *is* 0:

```py
import numpy as np

number = np.exp(-1j * np.pi)
print(number) # (-1-1.2246467991473532e-16j)

number = round(number.real, 10) + round(number.imag, 10) * 1j
print(number) # (-1+0j)
```

Answer (score 2):

While it's true that <sup>−</sup> = cos(−) +  sin(−) = −1, what `np.exp(-1j * np.pi)` passes to the `np.exp` function is *not* actually −, which is why you don't get zero.

Rather, `np.pi` is an *approximation* to  good to about sixteen digits—it has a relative error from  of under 10<sup>−16</sup>.

And 1.2246467991473532 × 10<sup>−16</sup>, though small (and perhaps “close enough” to zero for your purposes), is far from the smallest floating-point numbers, which go far below 10<sup>−300</sup>.

**What you see in the imaginary part of `np.exp(-1j * np.pi)` is not only a good approximation to value of the sin of `np.pi` (also with a relative error of under 10<sup>−16</sup>), but actually roughly the *absolute error* in `np.pi` as an approximation to !**

How can you tell?
The actual value of `np.pi` is 3.141592653589793115997963468544185161590576171875, which you can see by printing with up to 106 digits (more than needed to *disambiguate* between different IEEE 754 binary64 floating-point numbers, for which `3.141592653589793` is good enough, but this serves to show the exact decimal expansion):

```py
>>> '%.106g' % (np.pi,)
'3.141592653589793115997963468544185161590576171875'
>>> '%.106g' % (np.imag(np.exp(-1j * np.pi)),)
'-1.22464679914735320717376402945839660462569212467758006379625612680683843791484832763671875e-16'
```

Line these up and do schoolbook addition to full precision:

```
  3.141592653589793115997963468544185161590576171875
+ 0.000000000000000122464679914735320717376402945839660462569212467758006379625612680683843791484832763671875
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  3.141592653589793238462643383279505878966979117714660462569212467758006379625612680683843791484832763671875
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

And we have over 30 digits correct here!

Why does this work?
It works because for  near  sin() = ( − ) + (( − )³), by the Taylor expansion.
So when we compute sin(`np.pi`) = sin( + ) for some small absolute error , we get  − ( + ) + (³) ≈ .

---

**Note, however, that the sine function is *ill-conditioned* near .**
If you want to know what sin() is when  is near , but you actually have ⋅(1 + ) for some small relative error  in the input (perhaps because of earlier rounding errors, or because of earlier series truncation, or because of limitations in your measurement apparatus, or because of any other kind of approximation), you will get back sin(⋅(1 + )) = sin()⋅(1 + ) for some relative error  in the output, and  may be *arbitrarily large* even if  was very small.

In the worst case, if you evaluate sin at a point  near  such as `np.pi` when what you want sin(), you will get an infinite “relative error” because there is no finite number  such that sin() = sin()⋅(1 + ); sin() is zero and sin() is not.

So you should be wary of computations that rely on evaluating sin at approximations to points near —not because of floating-point, but because the sin function itself is ill-conditioned there.

In contrast, cos is well-conditioned near : small errors in the input shrink to even smaller errors in the output, which is why `np.cos(np.pi)` still returns −1.